# cake php passing the current logged in user array

Tags: php, cakephp

cakephp is amazing but this auth stuff i haven't gotten all the pieces, my question is simple. I want to pass the current logged in users array data so i can use it in a view. I use animal names as my testing names

```
class UsersController extends AppController {

     public function cat() {
        $this->set('cat',$this->Auth->login($this->request->data) );
            //I also tried $this->Auth->login()
    }
}
```

now my view
//cat.ctp

```
<div>
<?php echo print_r($cat)?> //returns 11
</div>
```

Comment: Why would you manually login then? You can simply use `$this->Session->read()` in the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your controller, $this->Auth->user() will return you an array with current user data.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can access user info via session helper in view file:

```
<?php print_r($this->Session->read('Auth.User')); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve authentified user's data from the controller using

```
$this->Auth->user();
exp: $this->Auth->user('username');
```